# php input save error

Tags: php, forms, file-handling

im trying to do simple save of form input with php.
im doing this on 000wehost.com
here is the output that goes wrong 
https://hikola.000webhostapp.com/

and here is my code in it.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and another myprocessingscript.php file

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['field1'];
$var1 = $_POST['field2'];

$handle = fopen("dataSave",'w');
fwrite($handle,$var1);
fwrite($handle,$var2);
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

can anyone tell me why wont it save a file with input values?
(im trying to do this for 3 hours already... thx..)

Comment: You got a syntax error notice the `}`, if that's a typo. You should turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` whilst your learning, then you won't spend 3 hours trying to debug a white screen.

Comment: i will literally kill my self........... thx -.-

Comment: Your also not setting `$var2`, only overwriting `$var1`